# Google Cloud Platform Network Routing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I currently have a 3rd-party vendor connecting to us over a VPN to our collocation.  I am trying to move that VPN to a Google Cloud Platform VPN.  I can/have created a few VPNs to a project and that is all very simple.

My problem lies in the requirements of our 3rd-party vendor.  They require that they send you traffic using the same IP as your VPN.  For instance, if my VPN endpoint is `2.2.2.2/32` and the 3rd-party is `5.5.5.204/32`.  They expect to send me traffic to `2.2.2.2/32`, to avoid overlapping CIDRs.  I accept that traffic from the tunnel and use a source NAT to route it to the correct place.  In turn, I use a destination NAT to route the traffic from a VLAN to the tunnel.

I am doing this using Juniper SRX and I understand the reason for the requirements, they are a huge vendor.  Before we put in the request we want to be able to prove we can do it and so far I am not able to create  this configuration in testing with GCP.

Is this possible at all?  It seems that there isn't any source NAT'ing at all.  I have looked at [Creating a static internal IP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking#set_a_static_target_ip_address).  I have looked at [Protocol forwarding](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/protocol-forwarding/).  Maybe protocol forwarding would work, but I don't see how if it does.  I know that I am going to be receiving TCP traffic on a specific port.  I am thinking that I could then create a target pool to forward that traffic to.  I still have the problem that they will only be sending me traffic to an IP that is not in the network and I can't see how to get it over without a NAT.

Comment: For other users looking at this thread this is being discussed [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/gce-discussion/CFVdJD-xGgA/6Z35Wo1uCwAJ).

Comment: @Faizan Why comment here but yet post [your answer](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gce-discussion/CFVdJD-xGgA/p0eL9m_TCwAJ) to only the Google Group, instead of also crossposting it here? (Spoiler alert: As of when this was posted, what OP is looking for couldn't be done on GCP.)

Answer (score 0):

As per Alex suggestion posting an answer to add visibility.

As [discussed here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/gce-discussion/CFVdJD-xGgA/p0eL9m_TCwAJ) this is not possible to achieve using [Cloud VPN](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/concepts/overview).

Nevertheless,  a new feature allowing multiple [NIC cards](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/multiple-interfaces-concepts) can ease the workaround of setting your own [VPN gateway](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/special-configurations#settingupvpn).